# Code for css table design with scrolling and minimize option

Tags: html, css

Actually i am looking for html table having scrolling option and also options for minimizing and maximizing the table(and better table design). I have spend hours trying to play around with this but have got nowhere.can u forward me ready code on net which can solve the problem?
I shall be much oblized to u?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkCaq/1/

Comment: You can't minimize a table using just CSS.  You'll need some JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Scrolling tables:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Collapsible tables:

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/how-create-collapsible-css-tables

Comment: thanks for reply
In first link(http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) i want to use multiple tbody tag in table tag like this
<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
 <tr>
  <th><a href="#">Header 1</a></th>
  <th><a href="#">Header 2</a></th>

  <th><a href="#">Header 3</a></th>
 </tr>
</thead>

Comment: <tbody class="scrollContent">
 <tr>
  <td>Cell Content 1</td>
  <td>Cell Content 2</td>
  <td>Cell Content 3</td>

 </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="scrollContent">
 <tr>
  <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
  <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
  <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

but not able to get desired result, What should i have to change in css for supporting multiple tbody section.

Comment: Have you tried it? There's nothing in the CSS that would prevent multiple tbody elements.

Comment: yes i tries this,But it is displaying only rows of first `code`<tbody>`code` tag. Rows in second `code`<tbody>`code` tag are not displaying.

Comment: Actually i am creating two tbody tag,In first tbody there will we one row and rest all of the rows will come in second tbody tag. so i m setting the height of `code`tbody.scrollContent `code` section in css.but not able to get desired result,Can u please tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with what you have so far and post it into your original question? Or post it here and I'll edit your question with it. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, I edited the fiddle (and your question to contain the link). Main changes are that the first tbody no longer has a scrollContent class, but all tbody elements have the width and display:block, as well as the td widths. Is that what you're looking for? Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/LkCaq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you put your table inside a div.

Try this & let me know...

```
<span onlcick="ShowHide('tblContainer')">Show/Hide</span>
<div id="tblContainer" style="clear:both;max-height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;">
  <table....>
      <define your rows and columns...>
  </table>
</div>
```

Put this jquery function on the page: ( assuming you are using jquery)

```
function ShowHide(id) { $("#" + id).toggle(); }
```

Comment: you need to adjust the max height accordingly